# Nested filter on Data Transfer Object using OData Wep Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a wep api project consumes data using odata but I'm having some problems with odata wep api.

when I execute that query

> /api/values?$top=50&$filter=Comments/Fortuneteller/FullName eq 'some string'

it gives me following error

> "Message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "The parent value for a property access of a property 'Fortuneteller' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value."

I don't want to return entity object from controller. Is there any way to filter the entity via DTO?

I'm using Repository + Service layer pattern in my project and structure of my project is like that

> api controller <-> service <-> repository <-> EF

**api controller**

```
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<FortuneDTO> Get()
    {
        return service.FiterBy((_ => true));
    }
```

**service**

```
    public IQueryable<FortuneDTO> FiterBy(Expression<Func<tblFortune, bool>> filter)
    {
        return repository.List().Where(filter).Select(_ => new FortuneDTO
        {
            CreatedByFullName = _.aspnet_Users.FullName,
            Id = _.FortuneId,
            Comments = _.tblComment.Select(c => new CommentDTO
            {
                Id=c.CommentId,
                Comment = c.Comment,
                Fortuneteller = new FortunetellerDTO { 
                    FullName=c.aspnet_Users.FullName,
                    Id=c.aspnet_Users.UserId
                }
            }).AsQueryable()
        });
    }
```

**repository**

```
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> List()
    {
        return context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    }
```

**DTO's**

```
public class FortuneDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByFullName { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CommentDTO> Comments { get; set; }
}
public class CommentDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public FortunetellerDTO Fortuneteller { get; set; }
}
public class FortunetellerDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 52):

As the exception message tells you, the query that you have is invalid.

```
/api/values?$top=50&$filter=Comments/Fortuneteller/FullName eq 'some string'
```

is equivalent to the linq expression

```
fortuneDTOs.Where(f => f.Comments.Fortuneteller.FullName == "some string").Top(50)
```

As you can see `fortuneDTOs.Comments.Fortuneteller` is incorrect as Comments is a collection and it doesn't have a property named 'FullName'.

You should use Any/All to filter on collections. For example, if you are trying to find all the fortunes where one of the commentators is 'some string', you can do

```
/api/values?$top=50&$filter=Comments/any(c: c/Fortuneteller/FullName eq 'some string')
```

If instead you want to find out all the fortunes where all the comments are made by only one commentator 'some string', you can do

```
/api/values?$top=50&$filter=Comments/all(c: c/Fortuneteller/FullName eq 'some string')
```

Comment: Thank you,I got the problem but now it gives me this error message that I can't figure out what it means 
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."

Comment: and inner exception  **"Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported."**

Comment: What if we want to use contains instead of eq ?

Comment: @EdizNezir then use:
`/api/values?filter=Products/any(p: contains(p/Name, 'some text'))`