# How do I map an OData nested filter query against a DTO to another entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, automapper

I am trying to test the ASP.NET Web API OData V4 $filter functionality.

I could map a non- nested filter query against a DTO to another entity easily following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628521/how-do-i-map-an-odata-query-against-a-dto-to-another-entity) without using AutoMapper.

But I want to map a nested filter query to a non-complex DTO.

eg. mapping `?$filter= SubProperties/Amount eq 100` against a DTO which has `Amount` field under `SubProperties` class and then further map it to a target DTO which has `Amount` property not nested.

GET products?$filter=SubProperties/Amount eq 100`

The Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public Properties SubProperties {get;set;}
}

public class Properties
{
    public double Amount{ get; set; }
}
```

The ProductDTO class:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

The ProductsController:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Product> options)
    {
       IQueryable<Product> products = this._products.AsQueryable();

        IEdmModel model = GetProductDTOModel();
        IEdmType type = model.FindDeclaredType(typeof(ProductDTO).ToString());
        ODataQueryOptionParser parser = new ODataQueryOptionParser(model, type, null, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "$filter", options.Filter.RawValue } });
        ODataQueryContext context = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(Product), options.Context.Path);
        FilterQueryOption filterMapper = new FilterQueryOption(options.Filter.RawValue, context, parser);

    }
}
```

When I expand on options -> Filter it has mapped correctly to the filter query string and FilterClause loads correctly. But after mapping it to ProductsDTO and expanding on filterMapper , FilterClause throws an exception, since it doesn't have a property SubProperties.

Comment: Versions? EF behind? Because the answers may vary WIDELY depending on that - dotnet core, ef core means "how much are you willing to write and are you willing to pull it all into memory first" until certain bugs are fixed in dotnetcore 3.

Comment: I was having similar issue and I got solution in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912222/nested-filter-on-data-transfer-object-using-odata-wep-api?answertab=active#tab-top